Can the impossibility of infinite regresses be solved if we assume only certain infinite regresses are allowed to exist?
Philosophers have plenty of thought experiments showing that an infinite chain of causes is logically impossible, meaning there's got to be a "first cause" at some point.
Take this example: "Imagine a universe with no beginning, where Smith, an immortal being, has been ringing a loud peal once every day for all of eternity. Suppose this peal is so loud that Smith would go permanently deaf after hearing it unless he was already deaf.
Given that Smith has been ringing the peal forever, he must have been deaf throughout the entire past, because each day's peal would have deafened him if he wasn't already deaf. However, this creates a paradox:
1. Smith can only be deaf if he hears the peal.
2. Smith has never heard the peal because he's always been deaf.
3. Smith is deaf.
These statements are inconsistent, revealing a logical impossibility. The paradox arises because time is infinite backward; if time had a beginning, Smith would have gone deaf on the first day."
But, what if Smith’s deafness isn’t permanent and gets cured regularly, letting him be deafened over and over? This could mean that universes with a cyclical pattern might handle an infinite past without any logical issues. The problem seems to pop up only in scenarios where something irreversible happens just once despite an endlessly stretching past.
This brings up a big question: what makes certain infinite-past worlds possible and not others? Some might argue this means that the laws of logic themselves have causal powers, which is a very controversial idea. Or maybe there’s some kind of backward causation, where the current state of the world decides if an infinite past can exist. This is also very controversial and seems to defeat the main point of explaining existence with an infinite regress of causes.
Can these issues be reconciled in a way that lets some worlds (maybe even ours) have an infinite regress of causes without falling into a paradox?

An infinite regress of causes is not logically impossible and is not a paradox. Many philosophers do find it undesirable for some purposes but not because of any logical issues. Infinite regress of causes seems metaphysically deficient, infinite regress of justifications does not seem to truly justify, etc. Infinite past, on the other hand, many find more acceptable. What 'decides' is simply philosophical preference, there is no need for causal powers of logic or backward causation.

In what sense? If we allow for some infinite regress, then it is not true that infinite regress is impossible. But impossible for who? Human reason, god,..?
